# I got cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'system.guid'? An Explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) error

Tags: c#

**My Controller**

Hi I got cannot implicitly convert type object to system.guid? An Explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) error in this line **taxinfotaxfiled.TaxFieldID = i**. Especially in "i" please any one give me the solution?

```
public ActionResult Create(TaxInfoTaxFiled taxinfotaxfiled)
    {
       ArrayList Alist = new ArrayList();
        {
            Alist.Add("FD713788-B5AE-49FF-8B2C-F311B9CB0CC4");
            Alist.Add("FD713788-B5AE-49FF-8B2C-F311B9CB0CC4");
            Alist.Add("64B512E7-46AE-4989-A049-A446118099C4");
            Alist.Add("376D45C8-659D-4ACE-B249-CFBF4F231915");
            Alist.Add("59A2449A-C5C6-45B5-AA00-F535D83AD48B");
            Alist.Add("03ADA903-D09A-4F53-8B67-7347A08EDAB1");
            Alist.Add("2F405521-06A0-427C-B9A3-56B8931CFC57");
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            taxinfotaxfiled.TaxInfoTaxFieldID = Guid.NewGuid();

            foreach (var i in Alist)
            {
                taxinfotaxfiled.TaxFieldID = i.Value;
               }

            db.TaxInfoTaxFileds.Add(taxinfotaxfiled);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

return View(taxinfotaxfiled);
    }
```

My Model

```
public partial class TaxInfoTaxFiled
{
    public System.Guid TaxInfoTaxFieldID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.Guid> TaxInfoID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.Guid> TaxFieldID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.Guid> FieldTypeID { get; set; }
    public string FieldValue { get; set; }
}
public partial class TaxField
{
    public System.Guid TaxFieldID { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public string PrintName { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the fact that `ArrayList` is not a generic class, and therefore knows nothing about the data it stores. Because of that `i` is an `Object`, and you cannot implicitly convert `Object` into a `Guid`. As the error message suggests, you can use an explicit cast, as in `taxinfotaxfiled.TaxFieldID = (Guid)i`. It might not work, because your ArrayList actually contains strings, and not Guids, in which case you will either need to change the way you populate your `ArrayList` to

```
Alist.Add(Guid.Parse(<value>));
```

or replace the way you get the value from the `ArrayList` to:

```
taxinfotaxfiled.TaxFieldID = Guid.Parse(i.ToString());
```

Or, even better, replace the `ArrayList` with a generic class `List<Guid>`, in which case the collection will know the type of objects it holds, and you will not need any casts.

Answer (score 1):

Change the line

```
taxinfotaxfiled.TaxFieldID = i.Value;
```

To this

```
taxinfotaxfiled.TaxFieldID = new Guid(i.Value.ToString());
```

Comment: The ToString() isn't necessary; i is already a string.  Also, these kinds of answers are better when they're accompanied by an explanation.

Comment: @RobertHarvey the element in the ArrayList is object not string. Because of that the exception is object to Guid. If he wrote in the loop var i it returns object !

Comment: You might want to try it that way anyway.  I'm pretty sure the implicit cast already succeeds.  My bad if it doesn't, but there are many places where it does.

Comment: @mybirthname Is correct, you do need a `ToString()`, or alternatively casting to `string`. Either way, you can't pass an object into `Guid`'s constructor

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace your code with this:

```
Alist.Add(Guid.Parse("FD713788-B5AE-49FF-8B2C-F311B9CB0CC4"));
```

And the same with the rest of your guids. Might be a better idea to use `List<Guid>` instead of `ArrayList`, too.

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
Guid.Parse(((Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView.GridViewCell)e.Row.Cells[cellIndex]).Value.ToString());
```